Error: React Hook "useQuery" cannot be called inside a callback
13:38 Error: React Hook "useQuery" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function. react-hooks/rules-of-hooks..
Below is my nextjs code
'use client';

import React from 'react';
// @ts-ignore
import CanvasJSReact from '@canvasjs/react-charts';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { OVERALL_PERCENTAGE_SECONDARY } from '@/app/graphql/queries/student-score/overallPercentageSecondaryQueries';

const CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;

const ScoreChart = ({ school, stfn }: any) => {
  const points = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

  const queries = points.map(point =>
    useQuery(OVERALL_PERCENTAGE_SECONDARY, {
      variables: { school, stfn, points: point },
    })
  );

  // Check if all queries are loading or have errors
  const loading = queries.some(query => query.loading);
  const error = queries.find(query => query.error)?.error;

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

  const overallPercentages = queries.map(query => query.data?.overallPercentageByPoints || { numof_question: 0, question: [] });

  const optionsChart = {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: false,
    theme: "light1",
    data: [{
      type: "pie",
      indexLabel: "{label}: {y}%",
      startAngle: -90,
      dataPoints: overallPercentages.map((percentage, index) => ({ y: percentage.overall, label: ["SA", "A", "N", "D", "SD"][index] })),
    }]
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p className='text-sm text-center font-bold'>Score Chart</p>
      <CanvasJSChart options={optionsChart} containerProps={{ width: '100%', height: '170px' }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ScoreChart;




The error occurs because React Hooks, such as useQuery, cannot be called inside a loop or a callback function. Hooks must be called at the top level of a React function component or a custom React Hook to ensure they are called in the same order on every render.
To resolve this, you should move the useQuery calls outside of the loop. Instead of making multiple useQuery calls inside the map function, you can either call them sequentially or create a custom hook that manages multiple queries. Here’s how you can handle multiple queries sequentially:
Sequential Queries
Define a Custom Hook for Multiple Queries:
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { OVERALL_PERCENTAGE_SECONDARY } from '@/app/graphql/queries/student-score/overallPercentageSecondaryQueries';

const useMultipleQueries = (school, stfn, points) => {
  const results = points.map(point =>
    useQuery(OVERALL_PERCENTAGE_SECONDARY, {
      variables: { school, stfn, points: point },
    })
  );
  return results;
};

Use the Custom Hook in Your Component:
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import CanvasJSReact from '@canvasjs/react-charts';
import { useMultipleQueries } from '@/app/hooks/useMultipleQueries'; // Import the custom hook

const CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;

const ScoreChart = ({ school, stfn }) => {
  const points = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
  const queries = useMultipleQueries(school, stfn, points);

  // Check if all queries are loading or have errors
  const loading = queries.some(query => query.loading);
  const error = queries.find(query => query.error)?.error;

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

  const overallPercentages = queries.map(query => query.data?.overallPercentageByPoints || { numof_question: 0, question: [] });

  const optionsChart = {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: false,
    theme: "light1",
    data: [{
      type: "pie",
      indexLabel: "{label}: {y}%",
      startAngle: -90,
      dataPoints: overallPercentages.map((percentage, index) => ({ y: percentage.overall, label: ["SA", "A", "N", "D", "SD"][index] })),
    }]
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p className='text-sm text-center font-bold'>Score Chart</p>
      <CanvasJSChart options={optionsChart} containerProps={{ width: '100%', height: '170px' }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ScoreChart;

Hope this will work.

did chatGPT give you the same response?!

Still have the same error bro 68
2024-06-06T08:53:13.522Z [WARNING]: Failed to compile.
[WARNING]: ./src/app/student-score/components/hook/useMultipleQueries.tsx
6:5 Error: React Hook "useQuery" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function. react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

okay.. can you share a sample repo or any other way to reproduce the issue?
